# Dropbox Java API - File owner emails

Tags: java, api, email, dropbox, owner

The `Java` API of `Dropbox` returns a list of file owner names via a method like

```
public List<String> getOwners(DbxClientV2 client, String fileId) {
  SharedFileMetadata metadata = client.sharing().getFileMetadata();
  return metadata.getOwnerDisplayNames();
}
```

Is there any way of getting the e-mail addresses, too?

Answer (score 1):

According to Dropbox v2 Documentation, it has endpoint - `/get_file_metadata`.

Example `curl` request:

```
curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/get_file_metadata \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer <access token> " \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data "{\"file\": \"id:3kmLmQFnf1AAAAAAAAAAAw\",\"actions\": []}"
```

Parameters:

```
{
    "file": "id:3kmLmQFnf1AAAAAAAAAAAw",
    "actions": []
}
```

Returns:

```
{
    "id": "id:3kmLmQFnf1AAAAAAAAAAAw",
    "name": "file.txt",
    "policy": {
        "acl_update_policy": {
            ".tag": "owner"
        },
        "shared_link_policy": {
            ".tag": "anyone"
        },
        "member_policy": {
            ".tag": "anyone"
        },
        "resolved_member_policy": {
            ".tag": "team"
        }
    },
    "preview_url": "https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/fir9vjelf",
    "access_type": {
        ".tag": "viewer"
    },
    "owner_display_names": [
        "Jane Doe"
    ],
    "owner_team": {
        "id": "dbtid:AAFdgehTzw7WlXhZJsbGCLePe8RvQGYDr-I",
        "name": "Acme, Inc."
    },
    "path_display": "/dir/file.txt",
    "path_lower": "/dir/file.txt",
    "permissions": [],
    "time_invited": "2016-01-20T00:00:00Z"
}
```

**`owner_display_names`** `List of (String)?` The display names of the users that own the file. If the file is part of a team folder, the display names of the team admins are also included. Absent if the owner display names cannot be fetched. This field is optional.

So, there are no information about user's email according to file.

Comment: Yes, that has been my impression too. I am hoping that somehow this information is available, as is in other cloud storage systems, like Google Drive and Box. Thanks anyway and +1.

Answer (score 1):

To get the information about the members of a shared file with the Dropbox Java SDK, you should use the `listFileMembers`* methods. There are a few versions you can choose from, depending on your use case and desired method of batching/pagination:

- https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#listFileMembers-java.lang.String-
- https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#listFileMembersBatch-java.util.List-
- https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#listFileMembersBatch-java.util.List-long-
- https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#listFileMembersBuilder-java.lang.String-
- https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#listFileMembersContinue-java.lang.String-

Comment: This is work if file was shared, and member was added (including e-mail address)

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the owners is via the collaboration metadata:

```
public List<String> getOwners(DbxClientV2 client, String fileId) {
  SharedFileMetadata metadata = client.sharing().getFileMetadata();
  List<UserFileMembershipInfo> users = metadata.getUsers();
  List<String> owners = new ArrayList<>();
  for (UserFileMembershipInfo user : users)
  if (user.getAccessType() == AccessLevel.OWNER) {
    owners.add(info.getUser().getDisplayName());
  }
  return owners;
}
```